# How to merge two dataframes with different lengths in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two weelly DateFrames, which are made-up of one column each, but with different lengths.

Could I please know how to merge them, maintaining the 'Week' indexing?

[df1]

```
Week              Coeff1      
1               -0.456662
1               -0.533774
1               -0.432871
1               -0.144993
1               -0.553376
...                   ...
53              -0.501221
53              -0.025225
53               1.529864
53               0.044380
53              -0.501221
[16713 rows x 1 columns]
```

[df2]

```
Week               Coeff    
1                 0.571707
1                 0.086152
1                 0.824832
1                -0.037042
1                 1.167451
...                    ...
53               -0.379374
53                1.076622
53               -0.547435
53               -0.638206
53                0.067848
[63265 rows x 1 columns]
```

I've tried this code:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='Week')
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
df3
```

But it gave me a new df (df3) with 13386431 rows × 2 columns

Desired outcome: A new df which has 3 columns (week, coeff1, coeff2), as df2 is longer, I expect to have some NaNs in coeff1 to fill the gaps.

Comment: Edit the post with what code you've tried so far, and why that isn't sufficient.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried, outlining what resources you've tried already

Comment: what is the problem with simple pandas.merge? please describe your problem

Comment: use `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Week',how='left')`

Comment: What is your desired result? There are many ways to merge two dataframes

Comment: @AnuragDabas, I tried, it returned a new df of 21070279 rows × 2 columns

Comment: @Burrito, I am trying to get a new df which has 3 columns (week, coeff1, coeff2), as df2 is longer, I expect to have some NaNs in coeff1 to fill the gaps.

Comment: The reason it is returning a dataframe that is millions of rows long, is because it is returning every combined match of the 'Week' collumn. For example, if df1 has 5 rows of Week ==1, and df2 also has 5 rows of Week==1, then the resulting merge will have 25 rows of Week==1 (5x5 = 25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your output should look somewhat like this:

| Week | Coeff1 | Coeff2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.456662 | 0.571707 |
| 1 | -0.533774 | 0.086152 |
| 1 | -0.432871 | 0.824832 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | NaN | 3 |

Don't mind the actual numbers though.
The problem is you won't achieve that with a join on Week, neither left nor inner and that is due to the fact that the Week-Index is not unique.
So, on a left join, pandas is going to join all the Coeff2-Values where df2.Week == 1 on every single row in df1 where df1.Week == 1. And that is why you get these millions of rows.

I will try and give you a workaround later, but maybe this helps you to think about this problem from another perspective!

Now is later:

What you actually want to do is to concatenate the Dataframes "per week".
You achieve that by iterating over every week, creating a df_subset[week] concatenating df1[week] and df2[week] by axis=1 and then concatenating all these subsets on axis=0 afterwards:

```py
weekly_dfs=[]
for week in df1.Week.unique():
    sub_df1 = df1.loc[df1.Week == week, "Coeff1"].reset_index(drop=True)
    sub_df2 = df2.loc[df2.Week == week, "Coeff2"].reset_index(drop=True)
    concat_df = pd.concat([sub_df1, sub_df2], axis=1)
    concat_df["Week"] = week
    weekly_dfs.append(concat_df)
df3 = pd.concat(weekly_dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The last reset of the index is optional but I recommend it anyways!

Comment: Under the assumption of df1.Week.unique() being equal to df2.Week.unique().

Comment: @lukas-kaspraslukas thanks a lot for your inputs. Following your code, I retrieve a df3 with 79889 rows × 3 columns, instead of 63264 x 3. Do you know how I could delete duplicates?

Comment: Yes, my bad! We have to reset the index for every sub_df because pd.concat(.., axis=1) joins them on the index. That is why we want sub_df1 and sub_df2 to start with rowindex 0 (and not the "old" rowindex the data may had). I edited the code; it should work now properly!

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot, Lukas! Well done :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment on the question, you may want to concatenate instead of merging the two data frames:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

The resulting `DataFrame` should have `63265` rows and will need some work to get it to the required format (remove the added index columns, rename the remaining columns, etc.), but `pd.concat` should be a good start.

Comment: thanks a lot, but my laptop is struggling to perform the task

Answer (score 0):

According to pandas' merge [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), you can use merge in a way like that:

What you are looking for is a left join. However, the default option is an inner join. You can change this by passing a different how argument:

```py
df2.merge(df1,how='left', left_on='Week', right_on='Week')
```

note that this would keep these rows in the bigger df and assign NaN to them when merging with the shorter df.

Comment: Assuming that 'Week' is the only shared column between the two dataframes, you actually don't have to pass 'left_on' or 'right_on'. Pandas will find the matching column and join on that automatically. In the event that there is more than one shared column, you can just call on='Week', which is the same as calling left_on and right_on